# Не работает transition на блок

Tags: css, scss

Есть ссылка, наводя на которую всплывает блок

Вот html:

```
<a class="outside" href="#">
    <div class="outside_hover cf">
        <i class="wood f_left"></i>
        <span class="f_left">Дерево</span>
        <p class="f_left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Alias debitis eaque est eum harum
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

и scss:

```
.outside {
    background: url("../img/outside.png") no-repeat scroll;
    width: 464px;
    height: 668px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    @include transition(all 0.2s );
    &:hover {
      .outside_hover {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        @include size(464px, 668px);
        position: relative;
      }
    }
}
```

Я хочу, что бы блок `.outside_hover` всплывал плавно и все что в нем, но сейчас `transition` не работает.

Comment: `transition` на `.outside_hover` у вас нет. Чего вы ожидаете? Значения по умолчанию для `background` на `.outside_hover` тоже нету. Что менять плавно-то? Укажите полный пример, на котором проблема воспроизводится полностью, а не кусок кода с `include`.

Comment: Да, действительно, пример как вырванный кусок кода.
Для плавного выплывания используйте transform: translate( ... );
transition не работает для display: none/block;